# Passing by refence fails when using the function call within a cout statement

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, cout

The usual concept of passing a variable by reference to a function is that you want to use that exact variable and not its copy, which is fine. But suppose you have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int dev(int &a, int b)
    {
        a = 5 + b;
        return b;
    }
    int main()
    { 
        int a = 0;
        int b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << dev(a, b) << " "<< a;
        return 0;           
    }
```

for inputs `a = 5, b = 10` I am expecting to output 10 15, but I get 10 5.

Now the problem goes away if instead of

```
    cout << dev(a, b) << " "<< a;
```

I write

```
int res = dev(a,b);
cout << res << " " << a;
```

I was wondering why it would be so?

Edit: spelling

Comment: `cout << dev(a, b) << " " << a` is undefined behavior. The standard does not specify in what order the expressions `dev(a, b)` and `a` are evaluated.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. I'd expect to do it in exact order specified, hence the confusion. Please answer the question, so I can credit you properly.

Comment: Generally it makes sense not to mix computations and output anyway.

Comment: @Bo Persson Alright, since this is marked as duplicate and _it is in fact_ a duplicate, should I remove it?

Comment: In general, avoid expressions having multiple subexpressions with side effects that affect the same variable. There are exceptions though where the order of evaluation is specified: the comma operator `,`, the ternary conditional operator `?:` and the logical operators `&&` and `||` are required to have their operands evaluated from left to right (with short-circuit evaluation on the latter two of course). All bets are off on other operations though.

Comment: @Vahagn - deleting is up to you. Generally, having more duplicates might help others find the answer.